# Postgresql on Windows and custom extensions

Tags: postgresql

I'm running Postgresql on Windows 10 and trying to install custom extension (https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) for logical decoding.

However, I have to build and install this extension manually. While building is possible via Visual Studio I can't find a way how to install extension via pgxs.  Pgxs seems to be missing in Postgresql distribution package for Windows and I can't find a viable way how to create extension.

`pg_config --pgxs` shows the following path:

```
C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
```

but this path doesn't exist.

Does anybody know how to install Postgresql extensions from source code on Windows?

Comment: PG is effectively useless on Windows, IMO

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan can you please provide cases in order to support your point?

Comment: For people seeking the wal2json Windows binary (who don't want to compile from source), I found binaries provided here: https://www.striim.com/docs/smsgc/en/smsgc-how-to-guides/postgresql-to-google-cloud-postgresql-migration-guide/set-up-the-postgresql-source.html After downloading, I just copied the dll file into the `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\VERSION\lib` folder, and restarted PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, I somehow got confused about extensions.

It appeared that everything is much simpler: I just copied compiled dll to postgresql lib folder and everything worked.

Detailed information about how to compile PostgreSQL extensions on Windows can be found here:
https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/

I'd like to add a note about `PGDLLEXPORT`. For extensions to work you should add `PGDLLEXPORT` before two procedures: `_PG_init` and `_PG_output_plugin_init`. So code will look like:

```
PGDLLEXPORT extern void     _PG_init(void);
PGDLLEXPORT extern void     _PG_output_plugin_init(OutputPluginCallbacks *cb);
```